# Send text from tableview to textfield

Tags: iphone, text, uitableview, uitextfield

I need to do this: when a user select a row from an tableview to send the text from that row to a textfield from an other tableview.
For example, if I select Services from 
[image]

I want to see Services here,near Type de Partenaire : [image]

I tried this :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

    NSLog(@"%@",cellText);
 self.recherchePartenaireTableView.partenaire.text=cellText;
}
```

and when Button ok is pressed :

```
-(IBAction)OkButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"BTN Ok");
    [self.recherchePartenaireTableView.tableviewrecherchepartenaire reloadData];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

but this is not working. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance..

**in implementation file for first image**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.backgroundView.opaque = NO;
        //cell.alpha = 0.65;

        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];

        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.opaque = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    [[cell textLabel] setText: [typePartenaireArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ;

    return cell;
}
```

** in implementation file for second image**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
            cell.backgroundView.opaque = NO;
            //cell.alpha = 0.65;

            cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];

            cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cell.detailTextLabel.opaque = NO;
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

            if(indexPath.row==0)
            {
                partenaire=[[UITextField alloc] init];
                partenaire.frame = CGRectMake(200,10,80,50);
                partenaire.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
                partenaire.text=@"Tous";     
                [partenaire setKeyboardAppearance:NO];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:partenaire];

            }

        }

        // Set up the cell...
        [[cell textLabel] setText: [arraytableview objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ;

        return cell;


}
```

Comment: You have to add the cellText to your DATA STRUCTURE OF the TABLE that is retrieved. Did you do that?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you be more explicit?

Comment: Have you try with UITableViewCell * selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0]]; ...?..and what print the NSLog statement?

Comment: NSLog from didSelectRowAtIndexPath print the text from first image..I didn't tried what you said,I don't know how to use

Comment: what you want exactly? have you print in second table's first row textfield which is selected from first table row?

Comment: no..in first image there are no textfield. If I select a row from first image I want to get the text from that row and put it in textfield from second image. By default it is Tous, but if I select Services I want to set "Services" to textfield near Type de Partenaire

Comment: where are you storing the contents of the text that appears in the tableview

Comment: Please post your code for - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath for the UITableView. In there you get the lines of your table. Put your new text into that structure!

Comment: Ok, so you have to show us the cellForRowAtIndexPath of the second image. Where/how you declare the "partenaire" variable?..a chance could be to call [tableView reloadData]; in the viewWillAppear.

Comment: I edited my question...UITextField partenaire is declared on RecherchePartenaireTableView, the class that populate the table view

Answer (score 1):

Override the init method of the second UITableView to accept an extra argument (in your case the text of the cell selected in the current UITableView). And in the second UITableView where you configure the cells, set their text as you wish with this parameter you just received from the previous tableView which the second tableview object was alloc initted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert your text into your array arraytableview in position 1 (arrays start at 0). Make sure it is declared as NSMutableArray otherwise you can't change it.

So you have to do: `[arraytableview insertObject: cellText atIndex: 1]` in your OK method. For this you might have to introduce a variable that holds the currently selected text to "transfer" it from the selected method to the OK method.

Or you just add it in your `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, but then it would add the text immediately without pressing OK. really depends what you want

I hope it's clear now.

Code to define UITableViewCell with multiple lines, textfields, etc:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self.contentView addSubview: imageView];

        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
        [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];
        [titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [titleLabel setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [titleLabel setLineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

        [self.contentView addSubview: titleLabel];

        description = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
        [description setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];
        [description setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [description setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [self.contentView addSubview: description];


    }
    return self;
}

    -(void) layoutSubviews {
        [super layoutSubviews];
        //  D_IN;   
        [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, 10.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
        [titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 1.0, 250.0, 40.0)]; //two lines
        [description setFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 37.0, 250.0, 3.0)];//not used

        //  D_OUT;  
}
```

Make sure that the layout is correct when specifying the starting x and y for each new component otherwise you won't see anything!!!

Then just set it with

```
 titleLabel.text =
```

or

```
description.text =
```

Comment: You didn't understand well want I must do...I must put the text from typePartenaire in second tableview which contains arraytableview and some TextFileds...so I cant do like you said

Comment: yes you are right, I have copied from the wrong text - I have edited the answer above

Comment: this is not correct too because the text from textfield is not in arraytableview

Comment: In your question you write: I need to do this: when a user select a row from an tableview to send the text from that row to a textfield from an other tableview. For example, if I select Services from enter image description here... 

I want to see Services here,near Type de Partenaire :   - So if you want to see the text "Services" next to "Type de Partenaire" this is what you have to do. Or please explain so I might understand better what you want...

Comment: I add the textfield to a certain row like this : if(indexPath.row==0)
            {
                partenaire=[[UITextField alloc] init];
                partenaire.frame = CGRectMake(200,10,80,50);
                partenaire.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
                partenaire.text=@"Tous";     
                [partenaire setKeyboardAppearance:NO];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:partenaire];

            }

Comment: so the textfiled is not in arraytableview...I don't know how to explain better...Do you know if I can add two text on the same row from table view in an other way (but not with NSDictionary) ?

Comment: If you want to "add" a text field to a tableViewCell then you need to realign all the textfields for the cell so that they all fit (see my sample code that I added). I don't change the structure of the tablecells during the app. If I need to add a text to a tableview I create the cell with two textfields and just set them whenever I need to. This also takes care of memory management. In your case you alloc a now UITextField - hopefully you make sure that this is release correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3627/discussion-between-gabrielle-and-user387184)